# Easy way to get the LON LAT of a list of cities

Tags: ruby, json, csv, geocoding

I have a list of cities in CSV format which I need to longitude and latitude for.

This is my CSV

```
GeoSearchString,Title
"New York", "Manhatten"
"Infinite Loop 1, San Francisco", "Apple Headquarter"
```

Now I am looking for an easy way to get coordinates for those places in JSON format

Comment: Besi's answer nailed the Manhattan geocoding, but there's a small problem with the second result for Apple Headquarters: Apple is actually not in San Francisco; it's in Cupertino (which, to be fair, is somewhat close to SF). Validating the address before geocoding might help avoid mistakes due to problems with input data. SmartyStreets link, where I work, is one provider of address validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the following script ([gist](https://gist.github.com/besi/5599117))

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
require 'geocoder'
require 'csv'
require 'json'
require 'yaml'


abort 'Usage ruby Geocoder.rb cities.csv' unless ARGV[0]

def main(file)
  puts "Loading file #{file}"
  csv = CSV.parse(File.read(file), :headers => true)

  results = []
  CSV.foreach(File.read(file), :headers => true) do |row|
    # Hacky way to skip the current search string if no result is found
    search = row['GeoSearchString'] rescue continue
    # The title is optional
    title = row['Title'] rescue ''
    geo = Geocoder.search(search).first

    if geo
      results << {search: search, title: title, lon: geo.longitude, lat: geo.latitude}
    end
  end

  puts JSON.pretty_generate(results)

end

main ARGV[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
unless ARGV[0]
  puts 'Usage ruby Geocoder.rb cities.csv' unless ARGV[0]
  exit
end
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
abort 'Usage ruby Geocoder.rb cities.csv' unless ARGV[0]
```

I'd replace:

```
CSV.foreach(File.read(file), :headers => true) do |row|

results = []
csv.each do |row|
```

with:

```
results = []
CSV.foreach(File.read(file), :headers => true) do |row|
```

Be *VERY* careful with:

```
search = row['GeoSearchString'] rescue continue
title = row['Title'] rescue ''
```

A single in-line `rescue` is a loaded, very large caliber, gun pointed at your foot. You have two. In this particular case it might be safe, without unintended side effects, but in general you want to go there very carefully.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments. I included your changes in my answer as well as the gist. Admittedly I am being optimistic when parsing the data. However I only wanted results that could be parsed in my JSON and the title is optional so for me it was not a problem if they are blank. I do like the "`rescue`-gun" a lot though :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your own database of cities, states, and other interesting areas (let's call them places) you can get that for free from the US Geological Survey [website](http://geonames.usgs.gov/domestic/download_data.htm).  It's called their Topical Gazetteer and has a massive amount of "places" along with geocodes.  You can get a full national file which is 80MB or just the Populated Places which is 8MB.  Additionally, you can download just the states you are interested in.

These places include:

> Populated Places – Named features with human habitation—cities, towns, villages, etc. Subset of National file above.
>
> Historical Features – Features that no longer exist on the landscape or no longer serve the original purpose. Subset of National file above.
>
> Concise Features – Large features that should be labeled on maps with a scale of 1:250,000. Subset of National file above.(last updated October 2, 2009)
>
> All Names – All names, both official and nonofficial (variant), for all features in the nation.
>
> Feature Description/History – Includes the following additional feature attributes: Description and History. This file is not a standard topical gazetteer file. If you need these additional feature attributes, you will need to associate the data, using the feature id column, with the data in one of our other files, such as those under the "States, Territories, Associated Areas of the United States" section.
>
> Antarctica Features – Features in Antarctica approved for use by the US government.
>
> Government Units – Official short names, alphabetic, and numeric codes of States

This is not going to be ZIP codes, but actual cities and towns.  Data that comes from the USPS will have lat/lon coordinates based on the centroid of a ZIP code (or group of ZIP codes that, when averaged, represent a city).  Because it is ZIP based, the lat/lon will be different than the data that comes from the USGS.  They're not interested in ZIP codes.  Also keep in mind that ZIP codes change monthly, whenever the USPS needs to revise their delivery routes.  Actual city locations really don't change.  (ignoring nominal tectonic movement).  So a definitive center point lat/lon may be best derived from the USGS data instead of the USPS ZIP-based weighted centroid.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, in my case this also has to work for european countries, but it would definitively be a good idea to have some sort of database or cache in case the geoparser restricts the number of request per minute or the like.